# Where to find the Disk Image Mounter? is not in Dash, where it is?

Tags: unity-dash, usability

I'm running Ubuntu 13.04. Disk Image Mounter is installed, but not located in the "Dash"
Where can find this utility to use?

Answer (score 3):

Disk Image Mounter is intended to be used when right clicking an ISO file:

[image]

By default, it's not shown in the Dash.

To make it visible, do the following:

1. `sudo nano /usr/share/applications/gnome-disk-image-mounter.desktop`
2. Go down to the line that begins with:

   ```
   NoDisplay=true
   ```

   And put a `#` in front of it.

   ```
   #NoDisplay=true
   ```
3. Save the changes by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, then <kbd>Y</kbd>, then<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Now, you should find it in the Dash:

[image]